# copy a formula down , but change the row number by adding 12

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I am converting a column in a sheet to multiple rows in another sheet. once I have populated the first row by referencing the addresses of the first 11 fields from the source sheet , I want to copy down the formulas to generate the next rows.
the first address is =Sheet1!A1, if I copy down it goes to =Sheet1!A2. Instead I want it to grab =Sheet1!A12 in the source sheet.

I tried to do it manually but it does not scale

Comment: Try: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, ROW(A1) * 11-10)`

Comment: Great - when I copy down , it works . But when I copy across to the next column on the resulting sheet, it does not . what would b the formula  in column B1 to grab =Sheet1!A2.

Comment: I want A2 form sheet 1  to go to B1 in sheet 2

Comment: Try this then: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, COLUMN(A1) * 11-10)`

Comment: I was not able to find the duplicate post, so I have posted an answer, there should be a duplicate post, it cant be, anyways you can refer my answer as well.

Comment: I figured how to do it . just need to change the 11-10 and it gets to the next row.

Comment: Also you can use a formula like this it will spill, enter in cell `A1` as 3 or 5 the number of rows and columns you need , `=LET(δ,A1, INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(SEQUENCE(δ)+{0,1,2})*11-10))` but it will give you a matrix !

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula, if :

> To Copy Down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,ROW(A1)*11-10)
```

---

> To Copy Right:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COLUMN(A1)*11-10)
```

---

[image]